# Can we prove the divergence of harmonic series like this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series, alternative-proof, harmonic-numbers

Let $S=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$.

Or $S=(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots)+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots)$.

$\implies S=(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots)+\frac{1}{2}({1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots)$.

$\implies S=(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots)+\frac{1}{2}(S)$.

$\implies \frac{S}2=1+(\frac{1}{3}+[\frac{1}4-\frac{1}4]+\frac{1}{5}+[\frac{1}6-\frac{1}6]+\frac{1}{7}+[\frac{1}8-\frac{1}8]+\cdots)$.

$\implies \frac{S}2=1+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}4+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}6+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}8+\cdots)+\frac{1}2(\frac{1}2+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots)$.

$\implies \frac{S}2=1+(\frac{1}{3.4}+\frac{1}{5.6}+\frac{1}{7.8}+\cdots)+\frac{1}2(S-1)$.

$\implies 0=\frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{1}{3.4}+\frac{1}{5.6}+\frac{1}{7.8}+\cdots$.

Which we know is not correct.

Also, we know that we do face this type of discrepancies when we are dealing with divergent series(as is the case when we put $x=1$ in the infinite geometric series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$) in the usual manner of dealing with convergent series.

Therefore, $S$ must be a divergent series.

Can we conclude something more/else from the last equation?

---

**EDIT**

Can we conclude that since the series is divergent and the partial sum of the terms is always increasing so, the only way it can be divergent is it($S$) has to be $\infty$?

Comment: what should be the $S$?

Comment: No, we can't. We _can_ conclude that careless manipulations of divergent or conditionally convergent series are dangerous.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Of course we can. If a series of positive numbers is convergent, it is absolutely convergent, and these kind of manipulations are valid for absolutely convergent series. Since the assumption of convergence leads to a contradiction, we can validly conclude that the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer We're speaking of $1+(\frac{1}{3}+[\frac{1}4-\frac{1}4]+\frac{1}{5}+[\frac{1}6-\frac{1}6]+\frac{1}{7}+[\frac{1}8-\frac{1}8]+\cdots)=1+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}4+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}6+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}8+\cdots)+\frac{1}2(\frac{1}2+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots)$, right? Absolutely convergent, right? Please...

Comment: @ProfessorVector We make the assumption of convergence for our proof by contradiction. **If** the assumption were correct, everything there would be absolutely convergent. At the end, we reach our proof that the assumption was incorrect.

Comment: Well, ok, if you see it that way... but there are less silly ways to reach a contradiction! :-)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think we can conclude that since the series is divergent and the partial sum of the terms is always increasing, so, the only way it(S) can be divergent is it has to be ∞.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can prove the divergence of the harmonic series like that, but one must at the beginning state something along the lines of "suppose the harmonic series is convergent".

Once that assumption is introduced, it is a valid proof by contradiction. Since all terms in the harmonic series are positive, if it were convergent, it would be absolutely convergent, hence also all of its subseries would be absolutely convergent, and all manipulations you made are valid for absolutely convergent series.

Since at the end you reach a manifestly false assertion by means that are valid if the assumption is true, it correctly follows that the assumption must have been false, i.e. that the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: I guess it is not a new proof. Right?

Comment: Can we conclude that since the series is divergent and the partial sum of the terms is always increasing so, the only way it can be divergent is it($S$) has to be $\infty$?

Comment: @ankit No idea whether this particular sequence of steps is new, but I'm convinced that similar ways have been used before. Though, since a direct proof is so easy, most often a direct proof would be used. // Yes, since all terms are nonnegative, there is only one way for the series to diverge, growing without bound, or, in other phraseology, to converge to $+\infty$.